# Generic Object to Specific Object Java

Tags: java, android, object, generics

I am working on an android app to access hardware across a network.    The function calls are the same for each hardware manufacturer but the response and parsing of the response will vary by manufacturer. My original idea was this:

```
public class ManufacturerONEobject {
    public void getURL(){ manufacturer Specific Code }
    public void postURL(){   manufacturer Specific Code  }
    }

public class ManufacturerTWOobject {
    public void getURL(){ manufacturer Specific Code }
    public void postURL(){   manufacturer Specific Code  }
    }


public class GenericObject(){

    ManufacturerONEobject manufacturerONE = null;
    ManufacturerTWOobject manufacturerTWO = null;

    if(manufacturer.equals("manufacturerONE"){
        manufacturerONE = new ManufacturerONEobject();
    }
    if(manufacturer.equals("manufacturerTWO"){
        manufacturerTWO = new ManufacturerTWOobject();
    }

    public void getURL(){  specificManufacturerObject.getURL();}
    public void postURL(){  specificManufacturerObject.postURL();}
    }
```

I chose this arrangement because it allows me to add new manufacturers to my app with just the addition of one global variable and an if statement in my generic object and all manufacturer specific code will be in its own class.  However, I will soon have 30 global variables with only one actually being used.  I looked at Generic Classes but I don't see a way to link the methods of my generic class to manufacturer specific class that will be determined at run time.  Is there a more elgant and/or efficient way to do this?

Comment: This seems like an extremely simple case of object oriented design and inheritance with a factory method.  Unless you're not explaining something well.

Comment: You don't need generics just add an interface that all the manufacturers will implement and a factory to  create the correct manufacturer.